# Room - check if data were fetched recently

Tags: android, dao, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

In official [Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) is an exaple of repository. There is a check if an object is existing in database and if is fresh:

```
// check if user was fetched recently
boolean userExists = userDao.hasUser(FRESH_TIMEOUT);
```

Any ideas how to implement that functionality (*hasUser*) for DAO?

Answer (score 7):

Most Architecture Components examples are available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components).
In your case, I couldn't find the UserDao class but there is a database schema sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/e49ba281a341c51fe0cda55e942b25f19bb14f22/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/schemas/com.example.android.persistence.migrations.UsersDatabase/4.json). `users` table has a `last_update` column. So you could write UserDao like this :

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE userId == :userId AND last_update >= :timeout)
int hasUser(int userId, long timeout)
```

It returns 0 if the user with id `userId` is not fresh enough.

Comment: I see, thanks. But how to implement the update of that value in DAO? I'm tempted to create [Extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) of a generated `@Insert` class

Comment: For insertions, you can define the table like this : `last_update DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. For updates, I would update User.last_update in every setter maybe before calling dao. (Edit : cleaned. sorry, cat intrusion on my keyboard :D)

Answer (score 1):

You should add an extra field to your table, like `COLUMN_LAST_FETCHED` with a date and after each interrogation, update that field with a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`RateLimiter`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/RateLimiter.kt) class as shown [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/RepoRepository.kt) in the android-architecture-components [GitHub project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) for a *non-persistent* way of checking if the data was recently fetched :

```
@Singleton 
@OpenForTesting 
class RepoRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val appExecutors: AppExecutors,
    private val db: GithubDb,
    private val repoDao: RepoDao,
    private val githubService: GithubService ) {

    private val repoListRateLimit = RateLimiter<String>(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

    fun loadRepos(owner: String): LiveData<Resource<List<Repo>>> {
        return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Repo>, List<Repo>>(appExecutors) {
            override fun saveCallResult(item: List<Repo>) {
                repoDao.insertRepos(item)
            }

            override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Repo>?): Boolean {
                return data == null || data.isEmpty() || repoListRateLimit.shouldFetch(owner)
            }

            override fun loadFromDb() = repoDao.loadRepositories(owner)

            override fun createCall() = githubService.getRepos(owner)

            override fun onFetchFailed() {
                repoListRateLimit.reset(owner)
            }
        }.asLiveData()
    }

    // Details omitted for brevity.
}
```

Comment: But this will not survive the user or the OS killing the application, or restarting the device?

Comment: @Alex indeed this solution is not persistent. See other answers for resiliency to process death.